# Salesforce create view with record type selection using url hacking

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

In an external app I'd like to have a button which can launch straight to case creation view in salesforce lightning including the record type selector.

Today, when I create a case by launching a url it seems to bypass the record type selector and defaults to a specific record type. This does not happen if I create the case from within salesforce directly.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Here are a couple of urls I have tried using to launch to new case creation from my external app. Each time it bypasses record type selection and defaults to a particular record type.

https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/500/e

https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Case/new

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom component to create case record with recordtype selection option. I don't think you can achieve this with URL hack. In custom component first page should be selection of recordType from picklist. After sleection of recordType you can utilize create:record event.